# Changing css in react-select component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-hooks, react-select

I have below select component in my react. I need to modify this component.

so I am using below code for it.

```
 const customStyles = {
        option: (provided:any, state:any) => ({
          ...provided,
          margin:'10px',
        }),
        control: (provided:any) => ({
          ...provided,
          height: '48px !important',
          'line-height': '2rem center',
          border: '#e6e6e6 solid 5px !important',
        }),
        input:(provided:any)=>({
            ...provided,
            'margin-top':'-25px',
        })
      }
```

below is select component.

```
  <Select
          id="sponsor" 
          name="sponsor"   
         placeholder={sponsor}
         styles={customStyles}
          options={result.map((sponsor:Sponsor)=>
                ({ label: sponsor.name, value: sponsor.id })
      )}
      >
```

actually seniors are not allowing to write css in `react jsx` file. is there anyway I can convert this `customStyles` code to `css` format? I tried a lot but its not easy to modify css for `react-select` component.

Comment: What do you mean by `not allowing to write css in react jsx file.`?

Comment: i mean can we write same style in .css file?

Answer (score -1):

const customStyles = {
option: (provided:any, state:any) => ({
...provided,
margin:'10px',
}),
control: (provided:any) => ({
...provided,
height: '48px !important',
'line-height': '2rem center',
border: '#e6e6e6 solid 5px !important',
}),
input:(provided:any)=>({
...provided,
'margin-top':'-25px',
})
}**strong text**